# finding similar strings in each row of two different data frame

Tags: r

I would like to check two data set. one data has many columns (this example has two columns **df1**) and one data has one column (**df2**)

At first, I want to check the first column of **df1** each row with all part of **df2** if any similar part is found, then the row number of df1 and df2 is written

for example 
Column 1 of df1 has two similar part of the row to df2 *Q9Y6Q9* in row 3 of df1 with *Q9Y6Q9* in row 4 of df2 . so the output is 3-4 , the same for others

Comment: I think your grammar is throwing me off and perhaps English is not your native language, but I'm not quite understanding. However, I think this involves using a `for` loop to loop through your two data frames, row by row and an `if` statement inside your `for` loop that checks if your condition is met and makes the edit if so.

Comment: Not sure what it is you are really after since your specification does not match expected output. But, here is a line of code that finds any 'substrings' in df1$sample_1 column in corresponding rows in df2. `apply(df1, 1, function(x) grep(paste(unlist(strsplit(x[1], ';')), collapse = '|'), df2$subunits..UniProt.IDs.))`

Comment: @Gopala thanks but the below is the right answer. however, I am still waiting for some modification , if you have any idea , you can adjust his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should normalize your data first. For instance, you could do:

```
normalize <- function(x, delim) {
    x <- gsub(")", "", x, fixed=TRUE)
    x <- gsub("(", "", x, fixed=TRUE)
    idx <- rep(seq_len(length(x)), times=nchar(gsub(sprintf("[^%s]",delim), "", as.character(x)))+1)
    names <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), delim))
    return(setNames(idx, names))
}
```

This function can applied to each column of `df1` as well as the lookup table `df2`:

```
s1 <- normalize(df1[,1], ";")
s2 <- normalize(df1[,2], ";")
lookup <- normalize(df2[,1], ",")
```

With this normalized data, it is easy to generate the output you are looking for:

```
process <- function(s) {
    lookup_try <- lookup[names(s)]
    found <- which(!is.na(lookup_try))
    pos <- lookup_try[names(s)[found]]
    return(paste(s[found], pos, sep="-"))
    #change the last line to "return(as.character(pos))" to get only the result as in the comment
}

process(s1)
# [1] "3-4" "4-1" "5-4"
process(s2)
# [1] "2-4"  "3-15" "7-16"
```

The output is not exactly the same as in the question, but this may be due to manual lookup errors.

In order to iterate over all columns of `df1`, you could use `lapply`:

```
res <- lapply(colnames(df1), function(x) process(normalize(df1[,x], ";")))
names(res) <- colnames(df1)
```

Now, `res` is a list indexed by the column names of `df1`:

```
res[["sample_1"]]
# [1] "4" "1" "4"
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I liked your answer already. I have two requests. can I make 1- a command that generate s1 to s number of columns of df1 ? so I don't need to make them manually. 2- only give me the rows number of df2 . for example process(s1) # [1] "4" "1" "4" .

Comment: Edited the answer to address your issues.